# Visual Studio 2019 Connected Service Key Vault

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have a very simple question. Where has the Azure Key Vault Connected Service gone in Visual Studio 2019 R3.

I have been using 2017 and decided to try 2019 but I rely on Key Vault for obvious reasons. However upon looking at the connected service page in the project there is [no Azure Key Vault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0yqr.png)

I have the [web development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPgPp.png) workload installed like the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service) suggests but still nothing.

As a comparison [2019 on the left and 2017 on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLKSC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Key Vault is also missing in the final version of Visual Studio 2019.

There is an open ticket about the issue and the Visual Studio Team is investigating it. I suggest you subscribe to the ticket, here is link:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/536404/visual-studio-2019-the-connected-service-key-vault.html